# Testcafe is passing a test that throws a JavaScript error

Tags: testcafe

I'm using Testcafe 3.3.0 with the following setup:

### .testcaferc.json

```json
{
    "browsers": ["chrome"],
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:4200",
    "src": "e2e",
    "reporter": [
        {
            "name": "spec"
        }
    ]
}
```

### menu.test.ts

```
import { e2eUser } from '../../roles/e2e-user';
import { clickFeatureMenu } from '../../helpers/feature-menu';

fixture('Menu')
    .page('./')
    .beforeEach(async t => await t.useRole(e2eUser));

test.only('Can click Profile menu item', async () => {
    await clickFeatureMenu('Profile');
});
```

I run testcafe via `testcafe --live`.

On the page the test is executing, I've added a simple `throw Error('Throw me!')` to check, if the test will fail.

To my surprise, it does not and it should.

I can see error in the browser window opened by testcafe:

```
hammerhead.js:42630 Error: Throw me!
    at new ActionFormFieldComponent (action-form-field.component.ts:35:15)
    at NodeInjectorFactory.ActionFormFieldComponent_Factory [as factory] (action-form-field.component.ts:52:6)
    at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:4738:44)
    at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:12592:27)
    at createDirectivesInstances (core.mjs:12008:5)
    at ɵɵelementStart (core.mjs:16299:9)
```

The error may come in asynchronous, so I also tried a `await t.wait(5000)` after clicking the menu item, but it does not help either.

I can see that the error was thrown in 5 seconds later Testcafe reports success.

I also tried explicitly setting `await t.skipJsErrors(false)` - does not change anything.

I'm out of ideas what could cause this behavior.

Thanks!

Comment: This information is not sufficient to reproduce the issue. Please create a separate ticket in the official GitHub repository using the following [bug template](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=TYPE%3A+bug&template=bug_report.yaml) so that the TestCafe team can research the problem. Please also refer to the following help topic: [how to create a minimal working example](https://testcafe.io/402636/faq#how-to-create-a-minimal-working-example-when-you-submit-an-issue)